# How to know the number of queued items in the ThreadPool backlog

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool, scalability

I'm designing a high scalable application. It'll have many processing nodes that get tasks from a common queue and process them.

My idea is to have a thread in every node that read from the task queue and starts a Task to do the work.

My problem is how to limit the number of queued Task's in every node, because it only depends on the speed of the thread that creates the Task's and not on the current load of the node.
How can I know the number of queued items in ThreadPool?
How can I do an fair distribution of tasks?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410959/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-items-in-threadpool-queue)

Comment: What do you mean by "processing nodes"? If they're just processors in a single shared-memory system, then you should rely on the default scheduler of the Task Parallel Library, which handles all those issues for you.

Comment: Just use a Semaphore/Slim.  Call Wait() before you start the task, Release() when the task completes.  How many unfinished tasks you allow is specified in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Each creation of the task from the common queue at the start should Interlocked.Increment the variable QueuedTaskCount, each task at the start should Interlocked.Decrement the same variable. The variable QueuedTaskCount now contains number of queued tasks.